# Sun Java System App Server on Netbeans 6.9.1

Tags: java, netbeans, servlets, jakarta-ee, glassfish

In adding a server on Netbeans 6.9.1 when SJSAPS 8.2 is chosen I receive an error.  Something to do with the location.  Can I use SJSAPS in Netbeans 6.9.1? Or have to use Java EE 5 which comes with Glassfish v2.  6.9.1 also has a choice for Glassfish v2.x but I get the same error.  Reading Sun's tutorial on "Servlet Technology."  See links:

[App Server Download](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaan.html)

[Servlet Tut](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnafd.html)

-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
Tools->Servers->Add Server->Add Server Instance - chose "Sun Java System Application Server 8.2"->Next

ERROR: "Server Location is not an "Sun Java System Application Server ..."
[image]

-*-*-*-*-*-*-*-*
How to get to the  [NB log file](http://blogs.oracle.com/NetBeansSupport/entry/netbeans_ide_log_file).

SERVER->LOG FILE - end of output here:

```
WARNING [org.openide.filesystems.Ordering]: Not all children in
Loaders/text/x-ant+xml/Factories/ marked with the position attribute: [org-
apache-tools-ant-module-loader-AntProjectDataLoader.instance], but some 
are: [org.apache.tools.ant.module.resources.xml-ergonomics.instance]
WARNING [org.openide.filesystems.Ordering]: Not all children in 
Loaders/text/x-ant+xml/Factories/ marked with the position attribute: [org-
apache-tools-ant-module-loader-AntProjectDataLoader.instance], but some 
are: [org.apache.tools.ant.module.resources.xml-ergonomics.instance]
WARNING [org.openide.filesystems.Ordering]: Not all children in 
Loaders/text/x-dd-sun-web+xml/Factories/ marked with the position 
attribute: [org-netbeans-modules-j2ee-sun-ddloaders-
SunDescriptorDataLoader.instance], but some are: 
[org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.sun.share.xml-ergonomics.instance]
WARNING [org.openide.filesystems.Ordering]: Not all children in 
Loaders/text/x-dd-servlet2.5/Factories/ marked with the position attribute: 
[org-netbeans-modules-j2ee-ddloaders-app-EarDataLoader.instance, org-
netbeans-modules-j2ee-ddloaders-client-ClientDataLoader.instance, org-
netbeans-modules-j2ee-ddloaders-ejb-EjbJar30DataLoader.instance, org-
netbeans-modules-j2ee-ddloaders-ejb-EjbJarDataLoader.instance, org-netbeans-
modules-j2ee-ddloaders-web-DDDataLoader.instance, org-netbeans-modules-j2ee-
ddloaders-web-DDWeb25DataLoader.instance], but some are: 
[org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.ddloaders.resources.xml-ergonomics.instance]
WARNING [org.openide.filesystems.Ordering]: Not all children in 
Loaders/application/x-class-file/Factories/ marked with the position 
attribute: [org-netbeans-modules-java-ClassDataLoader.instance], but some 
are: [org.netbeans.modules.java.source.resources.xml-ergonomics.instance]
WARNING [org.openide.filesystems.Ordering]: Not all children in 
Loaders/application/x-java-archive/Factories/ marked with the position 
attribute: [org-netbeans-modules-java-jarloader-JarDataLoader.instance], 
but some are: [org.netbeans.modules.java.j2seplatform.resources.xml-
ergonomics.instance]
WARNING [org.openide.text.CloneableEditorSupport]: 
org.netbeans.modules.properties.PropertiesEditorSupport should override 
asynchronousOpen(). See http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-
text/apichanges.html#CloneableEditorSupport.asynchronousOpen
WARNING [org.openide.text.CloneableEditorSupport]: 
org.netbeans.modules.xml.text.TextEditorSupport should override 
asynchronousOpen(). See http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-
text/apichanges.html#CloneableEditorSupport.asynchronousOpen
WARNING [org.openide.text.CloneableEditorSupport]: 
org.apache.tools.ant.module.loader.AntProjectDataEditor should override 
asynchronousOpen(). See http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-openide-
text/apichanges.html#CloneableEditorSupport.asynchronousOpen
```

Comment: Please post the error you get.  It'll probably be in the NB log file.

Comment: I have access to the IDE Log under the View menu??  Where is this NB log file??

Comment: <a href="http://blogs.oracle.com/NetBeansSupport/entry/netbeans_ide_log_file">NB log file</a>

Answer (score 0):

The error message that you are seeing basically means that the IDE does not think there is an install of SJSAS 8.2 in C:\Sun\AppServer.

If you installed SJSAS 8.2 in that location, then there is a bug in the IDE.

If you installed the server in a different location, enter the path of the install directory in the text field (or use the browse button).

If you haven't installed SJSAS 8.2 on this machine yet... you will need to do that first.